# Iterating through groups of 4

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, iteration

I have up to 16 datasets (only using 8 for the example here), and I'm trying to sort them into groups of 4, where the datasets within each group are as closely matched as possible. (Using a VBA macro in Excel).

My aim was to iterate through every possible combination of groups of 4 and compare how well matched they are to the previous "best match", overwriting that if so.

I've got no problems comparing how well matched the groups are, but the code I have won't iterate through every possible combination.

My question is why doesn't this code work? And if there is a better solution please let me know.

```
For a = 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 3
 For b = a + 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 2
  For c = b + 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 1
   For d = c + 1 To UBound(Whitelist)
    TempGroups(1, 1) = a: TempGroups(1, 2) = b: TempGroups(1, 3) = c: TempGroups(1, 4) = d

    For e = 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 3
    If InArray(TempGroups, e) = False Then
     For f = e + 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 2
     If InArray(TempGroups, f) = False Then
      For g = f + 1 To UBound(Whitelist) - 1
      If InArray(TempGroups, g) = False Then
       For h = g + 1 To UBound(Whitelist)
       If InArray(TempGroups, h) = False Then
        TempGroups(2, 1) = e: TempGroups(2, 2) = f: TempGroups(2, 3) = g: TempGroups(2, 4) = h

        If HowClose(Differences, TempGroups, 1) + HowClose(Differences, TempGroups, 2) < HowClose(Differences, Groups, 1) + HowClose(Differences, Groups, 2) Then
         For x = 1 To 4
          For y = 1 To 4
           Groups(x, y) = TempGroups(x, y)
          Next y
         Next x
        End If

       End If
       Next h
      End If
      Next g
     End If
     Next f
    End If
    Next e

   Next d
  Next c
 Next b
Next a
```

For Reference, UBound(Whitelist) can be taken as 8 (number of datasets I have to match)

TempGroups is an array which I'm writing each iteration to, so it can be compared to...

Groups, the array which will contain the data sorted into matched groups

The InArray function checks to see if the value is already allocated to a group, as the datasets can only be in one group each.

Thanks in advance!

Images:

[Datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOexX.png)

[Relatively Well Matched Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbMWM.png)

[Fairly Poorly Matched Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OejRG.png)

Comment: Well first of all this doesn't sound trivial at all. I'm not sure I understand the question entirely, is it possible to include some visual example of what you need to do ?

Comment: 1. Does this need to be in excel and VBA or are you using this as it's more familiar?
2. Can you include some snippets of the data, so we can get a feel for it?

Comment: @s-dunnim: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: @s-dunnim: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question with a lot more info, especially an example of the code I was trying to run - apologies for not attaching this first time around, massive oversight on my part!

Comment: @OurManinBananas Edited as requested, I hope that's better

Comment: @StefanJCollier It would preferably be in excel/vba, as that will allow me to directly copy data into a spreadsheet and just click a button to match the data. I've added a photo of psome of the data as well as some of the code I'd written

Comment: @S.Dunnim: your question has been placed on hold (closed as *too brad*)...if you want to have it re-opened, you will have to click *reopen* and show why it now meets the standards. If you need assistance with improving your question, maybe you could ask for help on Meta

Comment: @M.Douda I've updated the description and added some example code as well as photos, hopefully that's clarified it for you?

Comment: Sadly I don't think you can vote to reopen the question before you reach 250 reputation. I recommend deleting this question and asking again.

Comment: @OurManinBananas There's no reopen option for me... I was under the impression I had to edit/improve (which I have) and wait for it to be reviewed by others - am I missing something?

Comment: @M.Douda ah thank you for the advice. I'll give it a couple of minutes and do as you suggest if nothing happens.

Comment: @S.Dunnim Actually if you don't have the reputation needed, you can probably flag you own question as: In need of moderator intervention, and explain your issue

Comment: @M.Douda unfortunately it won't let me ask another question for 2 days as this one was poorly recieved! My own fault for lack of clarity I suppose. I'll leave this up and hope it gets revisited for now. I really appreciate all the advice :)

Comment: @S.Dunnim, sorry I can't help you then. Best of luck though! :)  Sorry about this trial by fire entry into stack overflow. Making a new question is probs your best shout. I think you can even delete this one to hide a bad rep (if you were worried).

Comment: I'd reccomend having a peek at other people's questions in the VBA section to get a feel for a good question format (also this does not sounds trivial. I wouldn't add that)

Comment: @S.Dunnim: I have nominated the question for re-opening. It will now go into the *review* queue, and may be re-opened if 4 more reviewers agree. You can also flag it for moderator attention, with a custom flag, explain your issue, that you have edited it to address the problems with it, and ask the mod to re-open it immediately.

Comment: Might be better to change the links into actual uploaded images, plus try to edit you question down to make it shorter, but still address your question

Comment: @OurManinBananas It won't let me embed images (not enough rep!), but I'll try and cut it down even more. Thanks for advice as always

Comment: @StefanJCollier thanks also for the advice, you're right it was a bit of a plunge into the deep end!